# Qual a finalidade de se utilizar um nome para expressões de classes em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, classes

Ao se utilizar uma expressão de classe *nomeada* em **Javascript** como no exemplo, eu não entendi como acessar **_Nome**, se é que seja possível para utilizá-la:

```js
let Nome = class _Nome {
  constructor(_nome) { 
    this.nome = _nome;
  }
};

let nome = new Nome('Fulano');
console.log(nome)

let _nome = new _Nome('Ciclano')
console.log(_nome);   // _Nome is not defined
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual é a finalidade de **_Nome**
- Se for possível acessar **_Nome**, como poderia utilizá-lo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O nome dado à uma expressão de classe tem como objetivo permitir o auto referenciamento enquanto a expressão é avaliada. Isto é, enquanto o JavaScript avalia a expressão para definir o valor de `var Nome`, esta variável ainda não será uma classe válida (você não consegue referenciar o valor de uma variável durante sua inicialização). Para contornar, você pode definir um "pseudo" nome para a classe, que estará disponível apenas localmente em relação à classe, o que justifica que você não consegue instanciá-la através deste nome.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
const Classe = class MinhaClasse {
  constructor() {
    console.log(MinhaClasse.name)
  }
}

const objeto = new Classe()
```

Dentro do construtor da classe, para auto-referenciar a classe "anônima" você pode utilizar o nome dado a ela. Esse mesmo nome pode ser obtido ao fazer `Classe.name`, porém apenas como uma *string*. Não há como instanciá-la a partir deste nome, até porque não faz sentido; se precisa instanciar pelo nome, basta não utilizar a expressão de classe, mas definir normalmente a classe nomeada.

Comment: Certo, então se entendi bem, não tem muita utilidade nomear uma expressão de classe.

Comment: A função é permitir auto-referenciar a classe... primeira frase da resposta. Se você precisa auto-referenciar, precisará dar nomear; se não precisar auto-referenciar, não precisará nomear. Simples assim.